# is it ok to re-use temporary variables?

Tags: php, arrays, counter

Like iterrating a array, and using the index variable later instead of count() :

```
foreach($arr as $index => $val){
  ...

}

echo 'number of items: '.$index+1;
```

?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *language* is explicitly OK with it.
I would not *recommend* it though, since it's unusual to reuse loop-specific values outside the loop and you may introduce bugs if you refactor your loop some time later and forget the dependency a few lines down. In fact, it's not a bad idea to explicitly `unset($index, $val)` after the loop to avoid such problems. This is especially true if you loop by reference (`foreach ($foo as &$bar)`).

Answer (score 0):

You can do that although I personally would not use it.

What if you need to change something later and for example skip an entry.

```
foreach($arr as $index => $val){
  if ($index > 3) continue;

}

echo 'number of items: '.$index+1; // now this will fail
```

So you CAN use it, but I wouldn't do it

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is a better choice:

```
foreach($arr as $index => $val){
if ($index > 3) continue;

}

echo 'number of items: '.count($arr);
```

Comment: Can you give some more explanation as to why you consider this to be *better*

Comment: it is better, because you can use your $index like you want. in the example of PeeHaa this can fail, well fail is not right, the index+1 is not the same like count($arr)